# No executable found matching command "dotnet-watch"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Trying to use `dotnet watch` but gettin an error:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-watch"

```
dotnet --version
1.0.0-rc4-0004834
```

Installed .NET Core 1.1 SDK and .NET Core 1.1 runtime

My `.csproj` file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils" Version="1.0.0-rc4-004771" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

`dotnet restore` has done

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools to your .csproj as below :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image: csproj]

then excute dotnet restore and dotnet watch run

[image: commandline]

Comment: Oh, thanks. I should use DotNetCliToolReference, my bad